# Bluetooth earphones doesn't connect automatically

Tags: bluetooth, alpine-linux, pipewire

After Alpine installation, I paired and trusted the earphone using bluetoothctl.
I have pipewire working, and pipewire-pulse installed (don't know how to check if it works).
These earphones worked correctly on previous Linux installation, that was Archlinux.

The problem: At startup, the command "bluetoothctl devices Connected" stays empty, I have to connect it manually to get the desired result (even after that the earphones don't emit sound but it is another problem).

The command "rc-status" tells me that bluetooth and dbus services are running as "default".
Here are the infos I can tell.